# How do I make use the of signing into google under online accounts? 14.04

Tags: email, evolution, calendar, online-accounts

New to ubuntu and linux, and so far I'm loving it. But one question I have is how can I make better use of the online accounts, specifically google. I found this in the help:

- Evolution, the email application. Your email account will be added to
  Evolution automatically, so it will retrieve your mail, give you
  access to your contacts, and display your calendar items in your
  Google agenda.
- Empathy, the instant messaging application. Your
  online account will be added and you will be able to communicate with
  your friends.
- Contacts, which will allow to see and edit your
  contacts.
- Documents can access your online documents and display
  them.

Empathy seems to be the only one that's working. Under the system setting I also see google calendar sync being an option. With my fresh install, I didn't have an evolution app, only thunderbird. But that didn't sync up with my google account, so I downloaded evolution email/calendar from ubuntu's software center. But I still have to reconfigure and re-authenticate my google account again manually in evolution. And even then contacts don't work, and it only shows one empty google calendar which also doesn't make sense.

I then tried the main contacts app, but when I tried to create an address book from online accounts it did nothing. I eventually created a local address book, but now I can't figure out how to try an online book again. The only option I see is to change address books, but that only gives the option to select existing ones (my one local). I don't see how to create a new address book again, never mind trying to make it an online one.

Finally, how do I access my online docs? Is that suppose to integrate something from google docs with libreOffice? I noticed there's a google drive filter in the unity dash, and I have unity-scope-gdrive installed. But it never actually searches anything in my google docs.

End result: with my fresh install and downloading all the latest updates of 14.04, what am I doing wrong? It seems like none of this google integration is working correctly.